# fetch() cancels with an AbortSignal, does res.json() too?

Tags: javascript, exception, async-await, fetch-api

I understand the workflow of cancelling an ongoing request with AbortSignal, which is to pass it to the options:

```js
const res = await fetch('/endpoint', { signal });
const data = await res.json();
```

However, what happens if the signal is cancelled *after* the request itself has finished, but *before* the data has been parsed? Like this:

```js
const res = await fetch('/endpoint', { signal });
// Cancel signal here
const data = await res.json();
```

[My tests](https://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/pt1fq8ao/) in Firefox, Chrome and Safari show that it will be properly cancelled and throw during that `res.json()`, but is it the official behavior?

```js
const log = (...text) => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${text.join(' ')}<br />`);

(async () => {
  try {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    const res = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', { signal });
    log('Request:', signal.aborted);
    controller.abort();
    log('Before:', signal.aborted);
    const data = await res.json();
    log('After:', signal.aborted);
  } catch (error) {
    log('Cancelled:', error.name);
  }
})();

// Request: false
// Before: true
// Cancelled: AbortError
```

From the output we can see it properly throws on `res.json()`, it never reaches the `After` step, and it's thrown with an `AbortError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the official behavior. `json()` (and friends) consume the response's body. And as per step 10 of https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-global-fetch that body can end up in an aborted state due to a signal. In that case, `json()` (and friends) will essentially rethrow.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, even though the hard spec is a bit difficult to read I believe it's what I am asking for, thanks!